# Is `asyncio.open_connection(host, port)` blocking?

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I am new to asyncio library and am struggling with the behavior of asyncio.open_connection. I have created a task and has `await asyncio.open_connection(host, port)`within it. I want the call to `open_connection` blocking, that is, don't yield to the event loop until the connection is established. However, my experience is suggesting that it is not blocking and yields to the loop. So here I have two questions

1. I want to make sure if `await asyncio.open_connection` really yields to the event loop?
2. And if yes, what is the best way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, it yields to event loop.

In asyncio's source code:

```py
async def open_connection(host=None, port=None, *,
                          limit=_DEFAULT_LIMIT, **kwds):
    """A wrapper for create_connection() returning a (reader, writer) pair.

    The reader returned is a StreamReader instance; the writer is a
    StreamWriter instance.

    The arguments are all the usual arguments to create_connection()
    except protocol_factory; most common are positional host and port,
    with various optional keyword arguments following.

    Additional optional keyword arguments are loop (to set the event loop
    instance to use) and limit (to set the buffer limit passed to the
    StreamReader).

    (If you want to customize the StreamReader and/or
    StreamReaderProtocol classes, just copy the code -- there's
    really nothing special here except some convenience.)
    """
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
    reader = StreamReader(limit=limit, loop=loop)
    protocol = StreamReaderProtocol(reader, loop=loop)
    transport, _ = await loop.create_connection(
        lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
    writer = StreamWriter(transport, protocol, reader, loop)
    return reader, writer
```

it calls `loop.create_connection` which is also `await` call, and about `loop.create_connection`:

> This method will try to establish the connection in the **background**. When successful, it returns a (transport, protocol) pair.

Says the Docs. So it is then yielding control to event loop and let other coroutines run, while previous coroutine is waiting in `await` for connection to be established.

---

2. If you absolutely sure you want to block the thread that is running the event loop then you can just use low-level [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html). Honestly I really am against this idea because there's not many reason to do so.

---

Just a minor addition, I saw you wasn't accepting answers on your previous questions. People write answers spending their own time and effort to help other peoples in help. If answer solved your questions then marking them as answer is a way to thank their efforts! Please refer [Stackoverflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more tips!